# Out-of-sample vs. in-sample interpretation

Tags: least-squares, out-of-sample

I am running predictive regressions on stock returns and as expected less relations hold out-of-sample than in-sample, however in some cases I find a significant relation out-of-sample but not in-sample at the usual significance levels (90%, 95% or 99%) for a potential predictor series.

Is this possible? How can this be interpreted? How could an iterative regression over the same dataset yield better results than using all the information at once...

To evaluate the significance in-sample I simply check the t-statistic of the slope coefficient and out-of-sample I use a mean squared prediction error based method which compares the errors of my model containing the potential predictor to a model containing only the historical mean return.

Comment: You seem to be confusing significance levels with confidence levels. The "usual" levels you cite are described as 10%, 5%, 1% significance levels. That aside, how does what you do out-of-sample lead to a significance level? That's not clear to me, perhaps others.

Comment: I am probably using the wrong words, sorry. I am looking for a series that is able to predict stock returns in a better way than the historical mean returns would. Thus in my OLS regression the dependent variable is the stock returns and the independent variable is a potential series that may have predictive power. My MSPE measure for the out of sample analysis compares the MSPE of the model with predictor series to the MSPE of the base model containing only the historical mean returns that's why it has its own significance levels.

Comment: Someone else may understand what you are doing, but I think you may need to post code and results to make it clearer.

Comment: here's a simlified example: consider regressing Series X on Series Y in-sample: let's assume the t-statistic of the slope coefficient is 1.2, clearly below 1.645 or 1.96, ... in a double sided test thus I cannot reject the hypothesis that it is equal to zero, thus no predictive power. My out of sample test however says that it has significally lower MSPE than the benchmark model (historical mean returns). How can it be better than any benchmark if in sample I showed that the model adds no value?

Comment: I see no code here, just a reference to an "out of sample test" on MSPE. That may be standard to some people, in which case they will give better comments.